# SQL reconnection instance (WPF)

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, sqlconnection, sqldependency

I have created a WPF program that shows some data drown by SQL from the network (using linq2sql).
I am using SqlDependencyEx to track changes or additions to that data and refresh my view accordingly.

However, if the network is interrupted for some reason, SqlDependencyEx drops the connection and when the network comes back, the view no longer refreshes with the new data.

Is there a way to know that the connection is back, so i can refresh my view and restart SqlDependencyEx instances?

Comment: Can you post some code?
At a guess, I'd suggest checking if the connection is open before using it. If it's not, reopen it.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush I don't know what code would help you.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush It is a listener on an SQL table.The listener creates triggers on the table and stored procedures on the DB, for installing and uninstalling the listener.
the uninstalling procedure, is called in the SQL,when the listener.stop() is called on my WPF program.
If the network is interrupted,listener.stop() cannot be called on the program,as there is no longer a connection to the SQL.
Then,when the network reconnects, if the WPF program has restarted, a new instance of the listener is created on the SQL and the previous, is left as trash.